# error while creating both of these tables or when foreign key contraints are added

Tags: sql, oracle

Whenever I try to create these two tables in oracle live SQL it gives right parenthesis error.

```
CREATE TABLE Section_Table (
Status_ID INT Primary Key,
Names varchar(20),
course_id int FOREIGN KEY references Course_Table(course_id),
Schedule_id int FOREIGN KEY references Schedule_Table(Schedule_id),
Instruction_id int
);
CREATE TABLE Enrollment_Table (
ENROLLMENT_ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
STUDENT varchar(20),
course_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Course_Table(course_id),
LEVEL_ID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Level_Table(LEVEL_ID),
Status_id INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Status_Table(Status_ID),
DATE_ENROLLED DATE
);
```

Comment: You haven't defined the tables referred to by the foreign keys.  It is not surprising they are failing.  Having a table called `section_table` with a primary key of `status_id` is really confusing ot me.

Comment: where are the tables Course_Table , Schedule_Table, Level_Table and Status_Table ???